# How to avoid line curvature in first layer of a 3D print

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, anet-a8, filament-quality

I have a problem with large lines in the first layer of my prints which have curvatures. The last layer has no problems. You can see the problem in the horizontal line of the "A", the rest of the "A" seems fine. Here are example pictures:

[image]

close up:

[image]

What can that be?

- This is printed with an Anet A8.
- Slicer: Ultimaker Cura
- Layer Height: 0.15 mm
- Wall Line Count: 2
- Print Speed: 60 mm/s
- Printing Temperature: 190° Celsius
- Build Plate Temperature: 60° Celsius

Comment: Level your bed properly... What is the first layer height? its speed and flow of first layer?

Comment: This looks like too much material for the room available; have you tried decreasing your flow maybe 5%?